# find files within specific date then copying them grep No such file

Tags: centos7

i am using centos7 and i want to find files that have been created at 9 Aug then moving them to another folder B under the root path

so I'm issuing the following command

```
find ./ -type f -ls |grep 'Aug  9' -exec cp {} /root/B \;
```

with the following error

```
grep: Aug  9: No such file or directory
   grep: cp: No such file or directory grep: {}: No such file or
   directory grep: /opt/B: Is a
   directory grep:  : No such file or directory
```

what is wrong in my command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command

`find . -type f -newermt 2017-08-01 ! -newermt 2017-08-10 -exec cp {} /disk1/ab/ \;`